# AngularJS: ng-intl-tel-input - How to get updated value?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS - I am using third party plugin ng-intl-tel-input. This is using for phone/mobile number showcase. All is well, populating placeholders(example phone number) based on country flag changes. Here I am facing problem that If entered value is incorrect based on country code & not valid number. Its returning null.. I wanna validate that & need to show user in valid number & need that updated number..How an I get?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="mobile" ng-intl-tel-input>
```

Comment: can you please fiddle it out.

Comment: How you are displaying error on form for invalid input ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Currently that I need to show..Usually I am using js validations..Showing notification if field entered is null

Answer (score 0):

You can check demo from below URL

> http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/

and html source code from below URL

> https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input/blob/master/index.html

Try by changing below code for input.

```
<form name="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.mobile.$invalid && form.mobile.$touched, 'has-success': form.mobile.$valid}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" ng-model="mobile" ng-intl-tel-input>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.mobile.$pristine && form.mobile.$untouched">Please type a telephone number</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.mobile.$invalid && form.mobile.$touched">Invalid :(</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.mobile.$valid">Valid :)    </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ranakrunal9. Can I get user updating value at watch or on click? using this plugin

Comment: sorry, i'm not getting what you are asking for watch or click ?